Two guys fighting over one's wife
Honestly, I do not remember in much detail. The guys in the movie may be brothers or they may be best friends.  In the movie, I believe it starts out in a boat area, with an underground fighting scenario. 
I know the guy has a wife, and I am pretty sure his brother/best friend needed a place to stay or whatever. While the husband was out fighting or doing whatever he was doing, the brother/best friend talked his wife into cheating with him, and the husband walks in to find him. So they fight and I believe he throws him through a banister, like the railings on a porch, or through the window etc. and at the end of the movie (I believe) they fight and one of them has to kill each other but the other one decides not to kill him after winning the fight (or decides to, I'm not too sure).
Can anyone identify this movie?

Language\country? Approximate decade?

Are you looking for the movie Brothers.
Storyline:

Before leaving on his second tour in Afghanistan, Marine Captain Sam
  Cahill, a leader, an athlete, a good husband and father, welcomes his
  screw-up brother Tommy home from prison. He'd robbed a bank. In
  country, Sam's helicopter is shot down and all are presumed dead. Back
  home, while Sam wastes away as a prisoner in a remote encampment,
  Tommy tries to take care of the widow and her two children. While
  imprisoned, Sam experiences horrors unbearable, so when he's rescued
  and returns home, he's silent, detached, without affect, and he's
  convinced his wife and brother have slept together. Demons of war
  possess him; what will silence them?

Trailer:




The movie could be Pearl Harbor. Considering the fact that the two main characters - Danny and Rafe played by Josh Hartnett and Ben Affleck, respectively are childhood best friends (almost like brothers). Rafe marries Evelyn (Kate Beckinsale) and goes to fight the war as a naval pilot. In an air-fight his plane is shot down and he is believed to be dead. In the meantime Danny and Evelyn eventually grow fond of each other and begin a relation, only for Rafe to come back from the dead. He is hurt and sees this as an act of betrayal by his best friend.
In one scene they fight it out on a beach shack after a few drinks. The movie ends with  Danny dying in the arms of Rafe after they crash land in Japan executing a retaliatory attack.
